# forcing matlab to use DAG network 'classify'

Tags: matlab, conv-neural-network, directed-acyclic-graphs, resnet

I have a ResNet50 CNN and I want to classify an image using it.
The code is
 `net = load('matconvnet-1.0-beta25/imagenet-resnet-50-dag');`

%net = vl_simplenn_tidy(net);

ori_ = single(ori); % note: 255 range
resized_ave_image = imresize(net.meta.normalization.averageImage, size(ori(:, :, 1)));
ori_ = ori_ - resized_ave_image;

dist_ = single(dist); % note: 255 range
dist_ = dist_ - resized_ave_image;

%% GBVS
gbvs_map = gbvs(ori);
saliency_map = gbvs_map.master_map_resized;

% Run the CNN.
[~, res_ori] = classify(net, ori_);
[~, res_dist] = classify(net, dist_);

but matlab use different toolbox for classify rather than DAG network, and because of that this code throws an error saying 'classify must have 3 arguments', how can I fix that?